# Order BY on column generated by select statement

Tags: sql

i'm running this query:

```
SELECT
     claims.rID
    ,claims.client
    ,clients.cName
    ,cur.currency
    ,carriers.scac
    ,carriers.cName
    ,claims.client+claims.counter
    ,claims.dateOn
    ,(SELECT top 1 errorCode FROM entries WHERE entries.rID=claims.rID) as errorCode
    ,(SELECT SUM(refundDue) FROM entries WHERE entries.rID=claims.rID) as amount
    ,auditors.initials

FROM claims
    INNER JOIN clients ON clients.code = claims.client 
    INNER JOIN currency cur ON claims.currency = cur.currencyID 
    INNER JOIN entries ON claims.rID = entries.rid
    INNER JOIN carriers ON carriers.carrierID = claims.carrierID
    INNER JOIN auditors ON claims.auditorID=auditors.auditorID

GROUP BY 
     claims.rID
    ,claims.client
    ,claims.counter
    ,claims.dateOn
    ,carriers.scac
    ,carriers.cName
    ,clients.cName
    ,cur.currency
    ,auditors.initials
    ,errorCode

ORDER BY errorCode ASC
```

The focus should be on the orderBy errorCode. For some reason, it's not actually ordering Alphabetically by errorCode. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: which rdbms is this?

Comment: What is the errorCode data type?

Comment: I'd guess because your alias `errorCode` is the same name as the column `errorCode` in your `entries` table. It sorts by the column, not your alias.

Comment: Always use the table_name or table_alias before any columns, for a plethora of reasons but clarity in this one.

Comment: the errorCode is type varchar(). I'll try renaming the error code alias and see if that works.

Comment: I changed the errorCode to eCode and now i get this error: Invalid column name 'eCode'. I'm no expert... how do i fix this?

Comment: Wow... forget it. Seems to work just find now. Thanks guys!

Comment: Last thing.... there's no answer that i can accept. Can you respond with an acceptable answer fancyPants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases don't allow you to use aliases created in the SELECT-list in the GROUP BY, ORDER BY and WHERE clauses. Instead, you have to repeat the expression used in the SELECT-list:

```
SELECT
    claims.rID,
    ...,
    (SELECT top 1 errorCode FROM entries WHERE entries.rID=claims.rID) AS errorCode,
    ...
FROM
   claims INNER JOIN ...
GROUP BY
    claims.rID,
    ...,
    (SELECT top 1 errorCode FROM entries WHERE entries.rID=claims.rID)
ORDER BY
    (SELECT top 1 errorCode FROM entries WHERE entries.rID=claims.rID) ASC
```

But I think that is better to use a sub-select as data source in the FROM-clause:

```
SELECT
    claims.rID,
    ...,
    E.errCode, E.amount,
    ...
FROM claims
    INNER JOIN clients ON clients.code = claims.client 
    INNER JOIN currency cur ON claims.currency = cur.currencyID 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT rID, MIN(errorCode) AS errCode, SUM(refundDue) AS amount
                FROM entries
                GROUP BY rID) AS E
        ON claims.rID = E.rid
    INNER JOIN carriers ON carriers.carrierID = claims.carrierID
    INNER JOIN auditors ON claims.auditorID=auditors.auditorID
GROUP BY
    claims.rID,
    ...,
    E.errCode
ORDER BY
    E.errCode ASC
```

Note that I included the `SUM(refundDue) AS amount` as well. If the error codes can be NULL within `entries`, use `MAX(errorCode)` instead of `MIN(errorCode)`.